# What are all of the registers inside the GPU called?

Tags: gpu, assembly

I have a GeForce GTX 980 GPU and wanted to know their register names and what they do so I can code my game in NASM for the physics, logic and communicating with the GPU Assembler. However, I haven't thought about the GPU Assembler and wanted help with one.

Comment: I'm...not quite sure GPU programming in assembly works the way you think it does.

Comment: So, I did a little research and now I am looking for a GPU ASM

Comment: There is no "GPU ASM". Different GPUs tend to have *wildly* different machine languages and internal architectures. This isn't x86. And while it can be useful to look at decompiled GPU assembly of some shader in order to understand where performance is going, no (unextended) API for interacting with GPUs that I'm aware of allows you to directly feed GPUs with their native instructions. There's *always* a compilation step, even for SPIR-V.